# How to complete brackets automatically?

Tags: balanced-parentheses

I use an auto complete tool in emacs, which can complete brackets. But I want to find out that how it determines whether it should complete the bracket. For example, assuming `|` stands for the point. In the case of `|  abc`, when typing `(`, it will auto complete to `(|)  abc`. In another case of `|abc` , when typing `(`, it will not auto complete just like what sublime does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142996/electric-pair-mode-dont-pair-if-cursor-precedes-a-non-whitespace-character

Comment: I had a hard time understanding the question, until I found `|` stands for the **cursor**. Not exactly what you want, but you can use `M-(` to insert a pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score 6):

The possible solution for this question I found is:
1) exclude the smartparens for it haven't support such a function.

```
dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '(smartparens)
```

2) add electric package when init

```
(electric-pair-mode 1)
(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)
```

Comment: Regarding smartparens, please see if the [recently added `sp-sublimetext-like` config](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/pull/1059/files) gives you what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your emacs init file

```
(setq electric-pair-preserve-balance nil)
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142996/electric-pair-mode-dont-pair-if-cursor-precedes-a-non-whitespace-character

Comment: @xuhdex Thanks, but it didn't work in spacemacs. Should I modify something?

Comment: Can it work under smartparens-mode?

Comment: @maple It is for `electric-pair-mode`. I don't know how to do it in `smartparens-mode`, but you can certainly switch to `electric-pair-mode` (which is builtin).

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to do that:

```el
(defun jp/insert-parentheses ()
"Insert a pair of parenthesis if next char is space or newline, or end of buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let ((c (char-after (point))))
    (cond
     ((or (not c) (= c 32) (= c 10)) (insert "()"))
     (t (insert "(")))))


(global-set-key "(" #'jp/insert-parentheses)
```

Where 32 is the code for a space character and 10 for newline.  The `not` thing is for when point is at end of buffer (`char-after` will return `nil`, and we want to allow insertion of a pair of parenthesis in this case).